# Consuming WCF service through KSOAP2 on Android gives errors

Tags: android, wcf, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I have the following [WCF webservice](http://50.19.226.15/Office365Admin/MsOnline.svc?wsdl)

I want to consume it in android client.My code so far is

```
public class SOAP_TestActivity extends Activity {

  private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
  private final String URL = "http://50.19.226.15/Office365Admin/MsOnline.svc";
  private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IMsOnline/ValidateUser";
  private final String METHOD_NAME = "ValidateUser";


  private final  String user_id= "khurram@office365trial.com.au";
  private final  String password= "friday@123";

  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regsubmitbtn);
        signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                        boolean auth=doLogin();
                        System.out.println(auth);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(auth), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
           });   
     }

    private boolean doLogin() {   

   boolean result=false;

   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

   request.addProperty("userid", user_id);
   request.addProperty("password",password);

   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new   SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

   envelope.dotNet = true;         

   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

   Log.d("myApp", request.toString());
   System.out.println(request);

   HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
   androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

   try {
           androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

           SoapPrimitive soapPrimitiveResults = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();                        

           Log.d("myApp", soapPrimitiveResults.toString());
           System.out.println("myApp" +soapPrimitiveResults);

                   if(soapPrimitiveResults.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
       {
                   result = true;

       }

   }catch(SocketException ex)
   {
       Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + ex.getMessage());
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + e.getMessage());
           e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return result;

   }
   }
```

This code works without any exception but I am not able to login into my application as the method `ValidateUser` always return false.This same webservice has been consumed in Windows Phone and is working without any problem.Also the username and password are 100% correct.

Looks like there is some problem in the `NAMESPACE` and `SOAP_ACTION`. I have gone through some tutorials and they say that the `SOAP_ACTION` is made by concatenating `NAMESPACE` with `METHOD_NAME`.So if I follow the tutorials my `SOAP_ACTION` should be

`"http://tempuri.org/ValidateUser"`

but the `SOAP_ACTION` given in the `WSDL link`for the method `"ValidateUser"` is

`"http://tempuri.org/IMsOnline/ValidateUser"`.

I am new to WCF Webservices and SOAP.Can anybody please tell me how to implement the methods given in `WSDL Document(link is at the top)`.
Looks like missing something important but don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

If the same web service works fine with windows phone, then you have a NameSpace problem,
and the web service method is not getting the parameters from the SOAP message. And since your ValidateUser gets no parameters, it just returns null/false.

I had the same problem. I solved it by explicitly defining a namespace hence getting rid of the default namespace WCF sets, tempuri.org

Here is my solution for reference:

[passing objects to wcf soap service from android using ksoap2; it sends and receives 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846149/passing-objects-to-wcf-soap-service-from-android-using-ksoap2-it-sends-and-rece)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...

Object response = envelope.getResponse();
String value = response.toString();

...
```